# How to dertmine the DirectionVector of a Line?

Tags: image-processing, pattern-recognition

I have a programming problem , in the context of a geometric shape recognition(Rectangles, ovals etc).
In this context, if I have a a simple line, from say (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) - made up of a series of points(x-y pairs) -

How would I calculate the DIRECTION VECTOR for this line? I understand the math behind it, but I'm finding the algorithm provided by my client a bit vague. I'm stuck at step 3) of this algorithm.
The following is the algorithm(in English as opposed ot psedocode), exactly as provided by my client.

1) Brake the points that make up a "stroke" or "line" up in to sets of X(where by default X= 20 - we will adjust) points = a PointSet

2) For Each PointSet, find the EndPouint(average of the points at the ends) for the first and last Y points(where by default Y= X/5).

**3) Find the DirectionVector of the PointSet= Subtract the CentrePoints**

4) For each pair of PointSets, find the AngleChange = the angle between the DirectionVectors of the PointSets.

and so on.......
I am trying to figure out what point (3) means......
Any help would be DEEPLy appreciated folks! THANKS in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the segment from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) is short, then you can approximate its direction vector simply by: (x2-x1)***i** + (y2-y1)***j**.

Otherwise, you could use [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) to estimate the direction vector as the principal axis of individual points forming the segment,

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I will opt for option a of your reply as the lines are broken up in to small segments before being analysed for various properties, including this DirectionVector.

Comment: Hi, forgive me for my seeming ignorance.. but what do "i" and "j"  represent in your above equation: (x2-x1) **i** etc

Comment: Vectors i and j (or e_x and e_y) form the standard basis for a 2D Euclidean space. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis